# Mongodb cluster vs. a basic VPS with same resources (digital ocean, linode..) minimum requirements

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean, vps, linode, system-requirements

I notice generically cloud infrastructure providers (like Digital Ocean, Linode..) offer "MongoDB Cluster" starting from 1GB of RAM at the cost of 15 usd.

The same providers offer "Virtual Personal Server" with 1 GB of RAM at less than 7usd.

Are there any valuable reasons (technical.. resources.. minimum requirements..) is advised to get the cluster when with less than half price is possible getting the same by a VPS?

Comment: These are usually 'fully mamaged' offerings. That generally includes high availability (replica set rather than a standalone), backups, upgrades, etc.  Landing page for DigitalOcean suggests the same. Whether or not these are worth the extra price is entirely dependent on you and your situation.

Comment: thank you, it sounds the answer I was looking for, I was worried there was something "more technical" I was missing